# AvalonDock - Bind MenuItem to State of DockableContent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, avalondock

I'm using [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com) to layout my application.

I want to create a "View" MenuItem with a checkable MenuItem for each of my DockableContents that will show/hide each item.

I'm not finding an example of anyone doing this, and it appears to me the State property is readonly, making it not possible to create a 2-way binding to the MenuItem.  It also looks like you have to call methods to change the State.

Anyone have a clever way to do this with bindings?  Or is there a simple way to do it I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use an attached property. The attached property would call the necessary methods to change the state. You could then bind to that.

```
public static class ContentAttach
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "State", typeof(DockableContentState), typeof(ContentAttach), new PropertyMetadata(StateChanged));
    public static void SetState(DockableContent element, DockableContentState value)
    {
        element.SetValue(StateProperty, value);
    }
    public static DockableContentState GetState(DockableContent element)
    {
        return (DockableContentState)element.GetValue(StateProperty);
    }
    private static void StateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (DockableContent)d;
        var state = (DockableContentState)e.NewValue;
        switch (state)
        {
            // Call methods in here to change State.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good start.  How would you get a reference to the specified Avalon DockableContent from within this static class?  And I'd have to make it 2-way somehow, so I'd have to register for an event on the DockableContent and change the value of the attached DP.

Comment: In the sample code, the specified DockableContent is the 'element' variable in StateChanged.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you'd set this property on MenuItem, but you'd really just bind to the DockableContent's property and it would get passed in.  I will try this.